# How to match user input with array data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, user-input, matching

I'm new in learning HTML, JavaScript and CSS. I'm stuck at this JavaScript code.

I'm trying to match user input on the searchbar with some city array list I already prepared, when the search result match the script will change the display style of element into showing the result of their search value, but until now the result always showing false value.

Is there any better way to do this? Is there something wrong with my code?

```js
 function searchRespond() {

    if (document.getElementById("myInput").value.match(cities))
    {
      document.getElementById("areaCovered").style.display = "block";
    }

    else {
      document.getElementById("areaNotCovered").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("searchResult").innerHTML = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
    }
  }
  var cities = ["Banda Aceh", "Bandar Lampung", "Banyuwangi", "Bandung", "Bali", "Batam", "Batu", "Bekasi", "Bengkulu", "Binjai", "Blitar", "Bogor", "Bukittinggi", "Cimahi", "Cirebon", "Denpasar", "Depok", "Dumai", "Gunungsitoli", "Jakarta", "Jambi", "Kediri", "Langsa", "Lhokseumawe", "Lombok", "Lubuklinggau", "Madiun", "Magelang", "Malang", "Medan", "Metro", "Mojokerto", "Padang", "Padang Sidempuan", "Padangpanjang", "Pagar Alam", "Palembang", "Pangkal Pinang", "Pariaman", "Pasuruan", "Payakumbuh", "Pekalongan", "Pekanbaru", "Pematangsiantar", "Prabumulih", "Prigi", "Probolinggo", "Sabang", "Salatiga", "Sawahlunto", "Semarang", "Serang", "Sibolga", "Solo", "Subussalam", "Sukabumi", "Sumbawa", "Sungaipenuh", "Surabaya", "Surakarta", "Tangerang", "Tangerang Selatan", "Tanjungbalai", "Tanjungpinang", "Tasikmalaya", "Tebing Tinggi", "Tegal", "Yogyakarta"];
```

```css
 .HeadlineSearchContainer {
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    margin: auto;
    height: 159px;
  }
  
  .SearchCharacterStyle {
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 24.82px;
    text-align: left;
  }
  
  .searchrespond {
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 24.82px;
    text-align: left;
  }
  
  #areaCovered {
    display: none;
  }
  
  #areaNotCovered {
    display: none;
  }
  
  #fillArea {
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<div class="HeadlineSearchContainer">
  <div class="SearchCharacterStyle">
    <h>SEARCH FOR AREA COVERANGE</h>
  </div>
  <div id="mySearch" class="searchbox_box">
    <form autocomplete="off" name="myForm">
      <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
        <input id="myInput" type="text" name="city" placeholder="Enter Your Destination City">
        <i class="searchbutton"></i>
      </div>
      <input type="button" formtarget="_new" onclick="searchRespond()" name="input" value="Search">
      <div class="searchrespond" id="searchRespond">
        <h id="areaCovered">YES! We cover your area destination</h>
        <h id="areaNotCovered">We don't cover your area destination yet
          <p id="searchResult"></p>
        </h>
        <h id="fillArea">Please fill your area destination first</h>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include all code for rendering the results, too.

Comment: _"is there any better way to do this?"_ - A working script. _" is there something wrong with my code ?"_ - Obviously. _"or something could help me solve this problem ?"_ -> Reading the [documentation of `.match()` ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match): _"The `match()` method retrieves the result of matching a string against a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)"_ -> An array is not a regular expression.

Comment: _"I'm new in learning HTML Javascript and CSS"_ - Then please ignore `var` and use `let` and `const` instead. Your script only "works" (using `cities` before it is defined) because of the behavior of `var`.

Comment: @CodeSpirit Could you run the code snippet ?, when typing "Bali" the return value always false

Comment: @Andreas okay, should I change the method and not using match ?, any suggestion on what to try for getting the same result ?

Comment: @Escade When I type "Bali" it display no destinations text and "Bali" below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do what you require you can use `filter()` to match the user's input to values in your array. You would be best to perform a case-insensitive match, which can be done by converting both values to the same case.

Note that this logic sets the notifications as hidden before the logic runs, so that the previous state of the search is removed.

In addition, I made a couple of improvements to the code. Firstly I stored the relevant elements in variables instead of accessing the DOM every time. This is slightly more performant, and makes the code a lot easier to read. I also used `addEventListener()` to bind events instead of inline event handlers in the HTML, which are bad practice and shouldn't be used. Lastly I converted the `<h>` elements to `<h2 />` in this demo, as there is no `<h>` element in HTML.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#myInput');
const areaCovered = document.querySelector('#areaCovered');
const areaNotCovered = document.querySelector('#areaNotCovered');
const searchResult = document.querySelector('#searchResult');
const fillArea = document.querySelector('#fillArea');
const cities = ["Banda Aceh", "Bandar Lampung", "Banyuwangi", "Bandung", "Bali", "Batam", "Batu", "Bekasi", "Bengkulu", "Binjai", "Blitar", "Bogor", "Bukittinggi", "Cimahi", "Cirebon", "Denpasar", "Depok", "Dumai", "Gunungsitoli", "Jakarta", "Jambi", "Kediri", "Langsa", "Lhokseumawe", "Lombok", "Lubuklinggau", "Madiun", "Magelang", "Malang", "Medan", "Metro", "Mojokerto", "Padang", "Padang Sidempuan", "Padangpanjang", "Pagar Alam", "Palembang", "Pangkal Pinang", "Pariaman", "Pasuruan", "Payakumbuh", "Pekalongan", "Pekanbaru", "Pematangsiantar", "Prabumulih", "Prigi", "Probolinggo", "Sabang", "Salatiga", "Sawahlunto", "Semarang", "Serang", "Sibolga", "Solo", "Subussalam", "Sukabumi", "Sumbawa", "Sungaipenuh", "Surabaya", "Surakarta", "Tangerang", "Tangerang Selatan", "Tanjungbalai", "Tanjungpinang", "Tasikmalaya", "Tebing Tinggi", "Tegal", "Yogyakarta"];

document.querySelector('#search-from').addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const searchTerm = input.value.trim().toLowerCase();

  fillArea.style.display = 'none';
  areaCovered.style.display = 'none';
  areaNotCovered.style.display = 'none';
  
  if (!searchTerm) {
    fillArea.style.display = 'block';
    return;
  }

  let matches = cities.filter(city => city.toLowerCase() == searchTerm);
  if (matches.length) {
    areaCovered.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    areaNotCovered.style.display = 'block';
  }
});
```

```css
.HeadlineSearchContainer {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  height: 159px;
}

.SearchCharacterStyle {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 24.82px;
  text-align: left;
}

.searchrespond {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 24.82px;
  text-align: left;
}

#areaCovered {
  display: none;
}

#areaNotCovered {
  display: none;
}

#fillArea {
  display: none;
}

.autocomplete {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="HeadlineSearchContainer">
  <div class="SearchCharacterStyle">
    <h>SEARCH FOR AREA COVERANGE</h>
  </div>
  <div id="mySearch" class="searchbox_box">
    <form autocomplete="off" name="myForm" id="search-from">
      <div class="autocomplete">
        <input id="myInput" type="text" name="city" placeholder="Enter Your Destination City">
        <i class="searchbutton"></i>
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Search</button>
      <div class="searchrespond" id="searchRespond">
        <h2 id="areaCovered">YES! We cover your area destination</h2>
        <h2 id="areaNotCovered">We don't cover your area destination yet</h2>
        <h2 id="fillArea">Please fill your area destination first</h2>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript includes().

```
<script>
const fruits = ["Banana Aceh", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];

let str = "Banana Aceh"; //document.getElementById("myInput").value

if(fruits.some(v => str.includes(v))) {
    console.log("Exists");
} else {
    console.log("Did not Exists");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 function searchRespond() {
let searchTerm = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
if (cities.find(city => city == searchTerm))
{
      document.getElementById("areaCovered").style.display = "block";
    }

    else {
      document.getElementById("areaNotCovered").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("searchResult").innerHTML = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
    }
  }
  var cities = ["Banda Aceh", "Bandar Lampung", "Banyuwangi", "Bandung", "Bali", "Batam", "Batu", "Bekasi", "Bengkulu", "Binjai", "Blitar", "Bogor", "Bukittinggi", "Cimahi", "Cirebon", "Denpasar", "Depok", "Dumai", "Gunungsitoli", "Jakarta", "Jambi", "Kediri", "Langsa", "Lhokseumawe", "Lombok", "Lubuklinggau", "Madiun", "Magelang", "Malang", "Medan", "Metro", "Mojokerto", "Padang", "Padang Sidempuan", "Padangpanjang", "Pagar Alam", "Palembang", "Pangkal Pinang", "Pariaman", "Pasuruan", "Payakumbuh", "Pekalongan", "Pekanbaru", "Pematangsiantar", "Prabumulih", "Prigi", "Probolinggo", "Sabang", "Salatiga", "Sawahlunto", "Semarang", "Serang", "Sibolga", "Solo", "Subussalam", "Sukabumi", "Sumbawa", "Sungaipenuh", "Surabaya", "Surakarta", "Tangerang", "Tangerang Selatan", "Tanjungbalai", "Tanjungpinang", "Tasikmalaya", "Tebing Tinggi", "Tegal", "Yogyakarta"];
```

```css
 .HeadlineSearchContainer {
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    margin: auto;
    height: 159px;
  }
  
  .SearchCharacterStyle {
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 24.82px;
    text-align: left;
  }
  
  .searchrespond {
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 24.82px;
    text-align: left;
  }
  
  #areaCovered {
    display: none;
  }
  
  #areaNotCovered {
    display: none;
  }
  
  #fillArea {
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<div class="HeadlineSearchContainer">
  <div class="SearchCharacterStyle">
    <h>SEARCH FOR AREA COVERANGE</h>
  </div>
  <div id="mySearch" class="searchbox_box">
    <form autocomplete="off" name="myForm">
      <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
        <input id="myInput" type="text" name="city" placeholder="Enter Your Destination City">
        <i class="searchbutton"></i>
      </div>
      <input type="button" formtarget="_new" onclick="searchRespond()" name="input" value="Search">
      <div class="searchrespond" id="searchRespond">
        <h id="areaCovered">YES! We cover your area destination</h>
        <h id="areaNotCovered">We don't cover your area destination yet
          <p id="searchResult"></p>
        </h>
        <h id="fillArea">Please fill your area destination first</h>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

suggest to validate input by making first letter uppercase and rest lowercase to match the array values

with javascript indexOf function

```
function searchRespond() {
var input = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
var area2search = input.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + input.slice(1).toLowerCase(); /* make fist letter capital and rest lower case to match array */
    if (cities.indexOf(area2search) > -1) {
     document.getElementById("areaCovered").style.display = "block";
    //In the array!
} else {
      document.getElementById("areaNotCovered").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("searchResult").innerHTML = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
   
}
  }
  var cities = ["Banda Aceh", "Bandar Lampung", "Banyuwangi", "Bandung", "Bali", "Batam", "Batu", "Bekasi", "Bengkulu", "Binjai", "Blitar", "Bogor", "Bukittinggi", "Cimahi", "Cirebon", "Denpasar", "Depok", "Dumai", "Gunungsitoli", "Jakarta", "Jambi", "Kediri", "Langsa", "Lhokseumawe", "Lombok", "Lubuklinggau", "Madiun", "Magelang", "Malang", "Medan", "Metro", "Mojokerto", "Padang", "Padang Sidempuan", "Padangpanjang", "Pagar Alam", "Palembang", "Pangkal Pinang", "Pariaman", "Pasuruan", "Payakumbuh", "Pekalongan", "Pekanbaru", "Pematangsiantar", "Prabumulih", "Prigi", "Probolinggo", "Sabang", "Salatiga", "Sawahlunto", "Semarang", "Serang", "Sibolga", "Solo", "Subussalam", "Sukabumi", "Sumbawa", "Sungaipenuh", "Surabaya", "Surakarta", "Tangerang", "Tangerang Selatan", "Tanjungbalai", "Tanjungpinang", "Tasikmalaya", "Tebing Tinggi", "Tegal", "Yogyakarta"];
```